# WinForm Control ListView "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Application goes well in XP,but when it change to Win7,the problem began.
i have checked up all my app codes,but find nothing.
ok,if i just put a single ListView in a new window,and run,also the same problem.
my english is not good,im tired with it,plz help me. thx very much.
[image: this the error message]

```
    public frmChooseBoxes(int flag, string complex)
    {
        otbList = Ocean_Turnover_BoxManager.GetOcean_Turnover_BoxesBySql("select * from Ocean_Turnover_Box where Status in (2,3) order by boxnum");
        //初始化选择框
        if (complex != "")
        {
            myNums = complex;
            string[] numbers = complex.Split(',');
            nList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string number in numbers)
            {
                nList.Add(number);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nList = null;
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(frmChooseBoxes));
    this.btnExit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnRemoveAll = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnRemoveSingle = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnAddAll = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnAddSingle = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnConfirm = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.lvSelectBoxes = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
    this.lvBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
    this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
    this.txtBoxNoChk = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.lblBoxNoS = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // btnExit
    // 
    this.btnExit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(375, 302);
    this.btnExit.Name = "btnExit";
    this.btnExit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.btnExit.TabIndex = 15;
    this.btnExit.Text = "退出";
    this.btnExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnExit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnExit_Click);
    // 
    // btnRemoveAll
    // 
    this.btnRemoveAll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 212);
    this.btnRemoveAll.Name = "btnRemoveAll";
    this.btnRemoveAll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
    this.btnRemoveAll.TabIndex = 14;
    this.btnRemoveAll.Text = "<<";
    this.btnRemoveAll.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnRemoveAll.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRemoveAll_Click);
    // 
    // btnRemoveSingle
    // 
    this.btnRemoveSingle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 183);
    this.btnRemoveSingle.Name = "btnRemoveSingle";
    this.btnRemoveSingle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
    this.btnRemoveSingle.TabIndex = 13;
    this.btnRemoveSingle.Text = "<";
    this.btnRemoveSingle.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnRemoveSingle.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRemoveSingle_Click);
    // 
    // btnAddAll
    // 
    this.btnAddAll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 96);
    this.btnAddAll.Name = "btnAddAll";
    this.btnAddAll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
    this.btnAddAll.TabIndex = 12;
    this.btnAddAll.Text = ">>";
    this.btnAddAll.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnAddAll.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAddAll_Click);
    // 
    // btnAddSingle
    // 
    this.btnAddSingle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(216, 67);
    this.btnAddSingle.Name = "btnAddSingle";
    this.btnAddSingle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 23);
    this.btnAddSingle.TabIndex = 11;
    this.btnAddSingle.Text = ">";
    this.btnAddSingle.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnAddSingle.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAddSingle_Click);
    // 
    // btnConfirm
    // 
    this.btnConfirm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(269, 302);
    this.btnConfirm.Name = "btnConfirm";
    this.btnConfirm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.btnConfirm.TabIndex = 8;
    this.btnConfirm.Text = "确定";
    this.btnConfirm.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnConfirm.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnConfirm_Click);
    // 
    // label1
    // 
    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 9);
    this.label1.Name = "label1";
    this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 16);
    this.label1.TabIndex = 16;
    this.label1.Text = "周转箱列表：";
    // 
    // label2
    // 
    this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(267, 9);
    this.label2.Name = "label2";
    this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 16);
    this.label2.TabIndex = 17;
    this.label2.Text = "已选择周转箱：";
    // 
    // lvSelectBoxes
    // 
    this.lvSelectBoxes.CheckBoxes = true;
    this.lvSelectBoxes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(269, 44);
    this.lvSelectBoxes.Name = "lvSelectBoxes";
    this.lvSelectBoxes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 228);
    this.lvSelectBoxes.TabIndex = 18;
    this.lvSelectBoxes.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
    this.lvSelectBoxes.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
    // 
    // lvBox
    // 
    this.lvBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 28);
    this.lvBox.Name = "lvBox";
    this.lvBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 244);
    this.lvBox.TabIndex = 19;
    this.lvBox.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
    this.lvBox.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
    // 
    // label3
    // 
    this.label3.AutoSize = true;
    this.label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(267, 25);
    this.label3.Name = "label3";
    this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(221, 12);
    this.label3.TabIndex = 20;
    this.label3.Text = "注：选中复选框表示此箱已满，不可再用";
    // 
    // groupBox1
    // 
    this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtBoxNoChk);
    this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lblBoxNoS);
    this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 279);
    this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
    this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 44);
    this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 21;
    this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
    this.groupBox1.Text = "筛选箱号：";
    // 
    // txtBoxNoChk
    // 
    this.txtBoxNoChk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 16);
    this.txtBoxNoChk.MaxLength = 5;
    this.txtBoxNoChk.Name = "txtBoxNoChk";
    this.txtBoxNoChk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(95, 21);
    this.txtBoxNoChk.TabIndex = 1;
    this.txtBoxNoChk.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtBoxNoChk_TextChanged);
    // 
    // lblBoxNoS
    // 
    this.lblBoxNoS.AutoSize = true;
    this.lblBoxNoS.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 23);
    this.lblBoxNoS.Name = "lblBoxNoS";
    this.lblBoxNoS.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 12);
    this.lblBoxNoS.TabIndex = 0;
    this.lblBoxNoS.Text = "匹配箱号：";
    // 
    // frmChooseBoxes
    // 
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(492, 346);
    this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
    this.Controls.Add(this.lvBox);
    this.Controls.Add(this.lvSelectBoxes);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnExit);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnRemoveAll);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnRemoveSingle);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnAddAll);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnAddSingle);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnConfirm);
    this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
    this.Name = "frmChooseBoxes";
    this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    this.Text = "选择箱号";
    this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.frmChooseBoxes_FormClosing);
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmChooseBoxes_Load);
    this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();

}
```

Comment: Add the piece of code that's causing the error so that people may help you.

Comment: Obviously this is not a generally reproducible problem. Everyone else can use the ListView control just fine on Windows 7. There's something different about your code, and there's no way we can help you fix it unless you show it to us. What properties did you set on the ListView? Are you adding items to it?

Comment: @user1770267 PLEASE stop adding code in the answer section.

Comment: i think this guy doesn't know how to internet.

Comment: @Inisheer sorry im new to satckoverflow

Comment: @user1770267 I know, that's why I said "please"  :P

Comment: @Inisheer am i post it in the right way now? <3

Comment: any guy know whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok,guys i finally find the answer,its the DotNetSkin.dll that cause the problem.
it cant work well in win7 or server2003,when i commend all the code in relation with it.The Application goes well.
thanks anyway :)

Comment: Did you have the fix for this issue? I had this problem with DotNetSkin as well.